# How do I convert this unicode string from a database to utf-8

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm getting the following from iterating through the items in a database call to sqlite3

```
(u'9', u'HS 09 - Coffee, Tea, Mat\xe9 and Spices', u'Bangladesh', 2000, 6127)
```

I need to convert it to utf-8, specifically, the second field `u'HS 09 - Coffee, Tea, Mat\xe9 and Spices'`    The resulting text should be :

'HS 09 -  Coffee, Tea, Maté and Spices'

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.encode('utf-8')`. EG:

```
>>> u'HS 09 - Coffee, Tea, Mat\xe9 and Spices'.encode('utf-8')
'HS 09 - Coffee, Tea, Mat\xc3\xa9 and Spices'
```

A note on terminology - the results of your database call are unicode. Your question text is correct that you want to convert (encode) the unicode object into utf-8, but your header was a bit off. I edited it to reflect this - a utf-8 encoded bytestring is not a Unicode string.

Comment: Wow, it's really that simple?  But even though the string has a u'' on it, surely the \xe9 is not a valid unicode character.  So it's not really utf-8, right? If so, how does python know how to encode the characters if it doesn't know what the original encoding of \xe9 is, eg. latin-1, iso-8859-2 etc.

Comment: I just added more context to the question, eg. that the resulting text should print out as 'HS 09 -  Coffee, Tea, Maté and Spices'

Comment: [U+00E9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) is indeed a valid Unicode code point.

Comment: @P.Jakobsen, yes `\xe9` is a valid Unicode character, U+00e9. To get the intended character, simply `print` it as is. If you print a list or tuple containing the string it will use the `repr` of the string, which will escape any characters outside of the ASCII set.

Comment: Others have answered this, but just for completeness - Unicode is a standard for assigning numbers to linguistic symbols like "lower case e with acute", as demonstrated at the link @tripleee gave. utf-8 is one of several ways to record those numbers as bytes - in this case `'\xc3\xa9'`. But the utf-8 encoding is not actually the code point. This is a complicated distinction, and despite the fact that it was written over 11 years ago I still don't know of a better explanation than the classic Joel on Software essay: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/unicode.html

Comment: I ended up solving the problem with: data[1] = data[1].replace(u"Coffee, Tea, Mat\xe9 and Spices",u"Coffee, Tea, Maté and Spices")    In fact, I'm not printing anything, I'm adding to a csv file, and that's where it fails unless I replace \xe9

Comment: What exactly is \xc3\xa9 ?  If \xe9 is already a valid unicode character as you say, why would encoding it to utf-8 actually bother changing to something else?

Comment: @P.Jakobsen that `replace` should have made no difference whatsoever; `u'\xe9'` and `u'é'` should be identical. Try `print data[1]` instead of `print data` to see what I was talking about earlier. The `encode` converts from a Unicode string to a byte string so it *should* have made a difference. Perhaps your file isn't UTF-8? If you were able to write a Unicode string to it directly, there was some implicit encoding going on.

Comment: Because UTF-8 and Unicode are not the same thing. UTF-8 is one of several ways to encode Unicode code points like U+00e9 into bytes. UTF-8 has the advantage that it uses the same bytes as ascii for ascii characters,  and the disadvantage that it requires multiple bytes for non-ascii characters. UTF-16, conversely, uses two bytes for most characters, etc.